# Grab file path from upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an RoR script that when given the file path for an XML file, will parse it.  I want to be able to find the file with the GUI, and then allow for my script to run.  Here's what I have in the view:

```
<%= form_for :setup, :html=>{:multipart=>true}, :url=>{action=>"create"} do |f| %>
<%= f.file_filed :my_file %>
<%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

The controller for the create area is:

```
$XML_FILE = params[:my_file]
routers = Router.new
@title = routers.overall_setup
if @title == "Everything worked" then
  redirect_to "/"
end
```

Basically from here, how do you snag the file path out?  I know that once the correct file path can be placed to $XML_FILE that the rest of the code works

Comment: It's a little unclear whether you want to know the local path of the uploaded file (impossible or at least - unreliable) or the uploaded file location on the server? You should rather focus on the content, since not all uploaded files will be stored on disk - some may be small enough to be returned to your action as IOString - which responds to .read methods, but does not represents a real file.

Comment: To clarify, the uploaded file location on the server.  By specs, the file will reside on the server as a permanent file.

Answer (score 9):

After you've submited a form you can find upploaded file this way:

```
path = params[:setup][:my_file][:tempfile].path
```

where `params[:setup][:my_file]` is your `file_filed` name in the form

#### Rails 3

```
path = params[:setup][:my_file].path
```