# Rails 4 file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using the file_field helper to upload a file. Following the file upload. This works fine to upload a file, but I would like to do some post-upload additional processing. For that, I need to know the source path, ie the full local file path, so I can use that to upload additional files without the use of a form. Any ideas on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Are you using any special gems for the upload, such as `Paperclip` or `Carrierwave`?

Comment: No, I am not using special gems. They all use ActiveRecord, and this is not something I would like to create a record for

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747254/grab-file-path-from-upload